# Delete last line from a string in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this one:

```
line1
line2
line3
line_i_want_to_remove
```

And I would like to remove the last one to receive something like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I know how to remove the first lines, I use this:

```
string = string.split("\n",3)[3]
```

But, How could I remove the last one?

Comment: You could access the last element of a list by using the index `[-1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer:

```py
string = '\n'.join(string.split('\n')[:-1])
```

longer answer:

```py
# split text on newlines, gives list of strings, one entry for each line
all_lines = string.split('\n')

# take a slice of this list, from beginning up until the next to last one
all_lines_except_last = all_lines[:-1]  # this is the same as all_lines[0:len(all_lines)-1]

# then join the remaining lines back together with newlines into a single string again
string = '\n'.join(all_lines_except_last)
```

Slice: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice

A few more examples on slice usage: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.